# Windows Batch copy folder with subfolders but not the files in the folder itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

I have a folder e.g. called Apples.

Inside that folder are folders starting from ATA, ATB, ATC and going to ATX.

Inside ATA folder (and all other AT* folders) I have an Excel file and folders from 01 to 12.

I want to copy all of the folders 01-12 but not the Excel file directly in ATA (just its subfolders and all their contents) and paste them in every other AT* folder.

Is there a way to do it? I don't mind manually having to type every AT* folder name.

Comment: See `xcopy /?`, check the `/T` switch

Comment: The thing is I need the files inside the 01-12, not just the folder structure.

Comment: @user628797 Please edit your question and show us source folder structure with files and wanted target folder structure with files as otherwise we are just guessing what you want and therefore waste our and your time. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41105725/3074564) for an example of a folder structure with files and read in another browser tab help topic [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to create such lists and use it as reference while editing your question.

Comment: And run in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` to get output the help for this command which has an `/EXCLUDE` option and option `/L` to test what would be copied without really copying.

Comment: I'd probably use two nested `for /D` loops, like this: `for /D %%A in ("Apples\AT*") do for /D %%B in ("%%~A\*") do xcopy /E "%%~B\*.*" "%%~A\*.*"` (I hope I got your intention right -- to copy the contents of the directories `01` to `12` one directory level up)

Comment: Not just one directory up, but first go one directory up and then copy into all the AT* folders.